# Is it possible to plot in new window by default in R?

Tags: r, plot, terminal

I tried to run some R scripts within a terminal and just found that I have to run 'dev.new()' first every time I want to make new plots.

Is it possible, with some environment settings, R in a Terminal could plot in new frame by default (like what Rstudio does)?

Thanks!

*Sorry, I made a mistake when asked the question. it should be a new plot in a new window (not a plot with a new frame). Sorry for the confusions.*

Comment: You're making a presumption, I think, that isn't entirely accurate. When R creates a new plotting window will depend on the specific code you're using to create the plot. Some plotting functions automatically trigger a new window, others do not, some provide an argument to control the behavior. It will be easier to help if you provide some example code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Basically, I am just using the very basic 'plot' function coming with the default 'graphics' package.

Comment: You are not being clear whether this is for scripts being called from a "Terminal" session ( on a Mac?)  or for interactive use.

Comment: What is the value of `par("new")`?

Comment: @DWin, sorry about that. I basically combine lines of R commands into an .r file and source it in the terminal. I am not quite sure this would make much difference.

Comment: @Roland, it's a FALSE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this should do what you want.

```
plot<-function(...){
  grDevices::dev.new()
  graphics::plot(...)
}
```

Comment: Oh wait, you said new frame, not device. Just change dev.new() to graphics::plot.new(). I'll leave my mistake in case someone comes here looking for how to open a new window each time instead of overwriting.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when asked the question. it should be a new plot in a new window (not a plot with a new frame). Sorry for the confusions. Your code works exactly the way I expected! Thanks.